# Correlation between categorical and numerical variables: TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have some problems in calculating correlation between categorical and numerical variables.
I have a dataset(head(5) shown below):

```
    A     C   Label
0   a1  gt2016  0
1   a2  gt2016  0
2   b13 gt2016  0
3   a5  gt2016  1
4   b12 gt2016  1
```

and I would like to find the correlation between C and Label. Since C contains categorical variables, I used a dummy variable as follows:

```
df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['C'])
del df_dummies[df_dummies.columns[-1]]
df_new = pd.concat([df, df_dummies], axis=1)
del df_new['C]
```

However, when I calculate the correlation as follows

```
x = df_new.values
correlation_matrix = np.corrcoef(x.T)
print(correlation_matrix)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Can you please give me if I missed a step in calculating the correlation in order to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that correlation is defined as

r = cov(X,Y) / sqrt(var(X) var(Y))

So you cannot have correlation with a constant since it's variance is 0, and C is always gt2016. But supposing there was variation, the following code would work for getting correlation between Label and each value of C:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a1', 'a2', 'b13', 'a5', 'b12'], 'C': ['gt2016']*4 + ['hi'], 'Label': [0,0,0,1,1]})

df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['C'])
df_new = pd.concat([df.drop('C', axis=1), df_dummies], axis=1)
df_new.corr()
```

Comment: Thanks Cameron. Yes, you are perfectly right. Actually they were the first 5 variables, my  C columns contains only two possible values, `gt2016` and `l2016`.